# Can't run DevForce Windows Store sample Application

Tags: devforce

I am trying to run Devforce WindowsStoreDevTour sample application.
However I am getting this exception:

System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'WindowsStoreDevTour.NorthwindIBEntities' threw an exception.
  Source=WindowsStoreDevTour
  TypeName=WindowsStoreDevTour.NorthwindIBEntities
  StackTrace:
       at WindowsStoreDevTour.NorthwindIBEntities..ctor(Boolean shouldConnect, String dataSourceExtension, EntityServiceOption entityServiceOption, String compositionContextName)
       at WindowsStoreDevTour.DataService..ctor()
       at WindowsStoreDevTour.DataService.get_Instance()
       at WindowsStoreDevTour.ListPage.d__0.MoveNext()
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=The type initializer for 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityMetadataStore' threw an exception.
       Source=IdeaBlade.EntityModel.WinRT
       TypeName=IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityMetadataStore
       StackTrace:
            at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityMetadataStore.get_Instance()
            at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityRelation.get_MetadataStore()
            at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityRelation.InitializeEntityRelations(Assembly assembly)
            at WindowsStoreDevTour.NorthwindIBEntities..cctor()
       InnerException: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
            HResult=-2146232830
            Message=Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
                 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
                 at IdeaBlade.Core.Reflection.ReflectionExtensions.GetAllTypes(Assembly assembly)
                 at IdeaBlade.Core.PlatformResolver.b__0[T](Assembly a)
                 at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__14`2.MoveNext()
                 at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
                 at IdeaBlade.Core.PlatformResolver.Resolve[T](Boolean throwIfNotFound)
                 at IdeaBlade.Core.AppEnv.get_Current()
                 at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityMetadataStore..ctor()
                 at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityMetadataStore..cctor()
            InnerException:

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: We haven't seen this problem before.  Can you tell me anything about your environment - the versions of Windows 8, Visual Studio and DevForce?  When did you download the sample?

Comment: Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, DevForce 2012. I have downloaded the sample today, from here : http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-windows-store-tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we forgot to update the packages.config entry for the newer Microsoft.Composition package used in version 7.2.3.  You can fix this by going to the NuGet Package Manager and updating this package to the latest version (1.0.27).

We'll get the sample fixed soon.